# Angular 5: How can I further filter my data down based upon the valueChanges event

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

My ultimate goal is to get autocomplete to work, however my question is: 
How can I further filter my data down based upon the valueChanges event?

I'm looking not just for the correct code but an explanation on how. Since this is my first attempt at Angular/React coding.

Currently I have the following code.

gizmo.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Add Gizmo"
           #addGizmo
           [formControl]="gizmoControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           [matChipInputFor] ="gizmoChipList"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addGizmo($event)"
           />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-chip-list #tagChipList>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let gimzo of data.gizmos"
                [selectable]="isSelectable"
                color="accent"
                [removable]="isRemovable" (removed)="removeGizmo(gizmo)">{{tag}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="isRemovable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let gizmo of filterGizmos | async" [value]="gizmo">
      {{gizmo.value}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

gizmo.ts

```
gizmoControl = new FormControl();
private filterGizmos: Observable<Gizmo[]>;

filterGizmoData(): Observable<Gizmo[]> {
         return this.dataService.findGizmos(new GizmoParameters()).map(x => x.filter(y => this.data.gizmos.includes(y.value)));
};

addGizmo(event: MatChipInputElement){
// Logic to add item
this.filterGizmos = this.filterGizmoData();
};

deleteGizmo(item: string){
  //Logic to remove item 
  this.filterGizmos = this.filterGizmoData();
};

ngOnInit() {    
this.dataService.getGizmo(this.gizmoId)     
  .subscribe(x => {
    // Logic to load data for view...

    this.filterGizmos = this.filterGizmoData();
  });


this.filterGizmos = this.gizmoControl.valueChanges.pipe(map(x => this.filter(x)));
```

}

I have a list of chips (data.Gizmos) showing which gimzos the user already selected.

In the input the user can select a gizmo to add and the user can delete the gizmo from chip list.  When this occurs I make sure to add/remove the selected gizmos from the available options (filterGizmos)

I've read through the Angular Material examples, but I can't seem to get the autocomplete to work in my code.

I've tried this in the constructor:

```
this.filterGizmos = this.gizmoControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  map((name: string | null) => name ? this.filter(name) : this.filterGizmos));
```

However I get the error:

```
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: If you create a small repro on Stackblitz it'd be easier to help you out. Here's a starter with material: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think autocomplete is not working because `this.filterGizmo` will be overwritten with `this.filterGizmoData();`.

There is chance that the code `this.filterGizmos = this.gizmoControl.valueChanges.pipe(map(x => this.filter(x)));` could run before the subscription in `this.dataService.getGizmo(this.gizmoId)` because it will run asynchronously.

I think this could be solved when you assign the value from your dataservice to variable and filter that variable, e.g.:

```
myGizmos: any[]; 
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getGizmo(this.gizmoId).subscribe(data => {
    this.myGizmos = data;
    this.filterGizmos = this.gizmoControl.valueChanges.pipe(map(x => this.filter(x)));
  });
}
```

Please also look at sample  at stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqqvek